# WhenEvent used in a PDE to output independent variable

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, event-detection

I want to use WhenEvent with a PDE after it has reached steady state. I'm posting a system of 2 equations (my real system has 6) and I'm solving the advection-diffusion-reaction 2nd order PDE.

First I set up the PDE:

```
pde = {
D[p1[z, t], t] == Dif D[p1[z, t], z, z] - v D[p1[z, t], z] - kp1 p1[z, t], 
D[p2[z, t], t] == Dif D[p2[z, t], z, z] - v D[p2[z, t], z] - kp2 p2[z, t] + kp1 p1[z, t]};

ic = {p1[z, 0] == p1in, p2[z, 0] == p2in};

bcs = {
v p1in == (v p1[z, t] - Dif D[p1[z, t], z] /. z -> 0), (D[p1[z, t],z] /. z -> l) == 0, 
v p2in == (v p2[z, t] - Dif D[p2[z, t], z] /. z -> 0), (D[p2[z, t],z] /. z -> l) == 0
};

params = {Dif -> 0.01, v -> 2, l -> 15, cin1 -> 10, p1in -> 30, p2in -> 60, kp1 -> 0.1, kp2 -> 0.05};

soli =NDSolve[
{pde, ic, bcs} /. params, {p1[z, t], p2[z, t]}, {z, 0, 15}, {t, 0, 100}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" ->{"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 750}}];
```

I want to use `WhenEvent` to output the distance (i.e. `z-variable`) it takes for `p1[z,t]` (or `p2[z,t]`) to reach a chosen value. Something along the lines of:

`WhenEvent[{p1[z,t]==20}, Print[`distance along z`]`

My approach:

First I tried adding WhenEvent into `soli` like this:

```
soli =NDSolve[{pde, ic, bcs, WhenEvent[{p1[z, t] == 20}, {Print[z]}]} /. 
params, {p1[z, t], p2[z, t]}, {z, 0, 15}, {t, 0, 100}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 750}}];
```

That gave me all sorts of errors. My question is how do I get it to print out the distance along z that it take for `p1[z,t]` to decay to 20?

Attempt: Then I was wondering if I should discretize the solution so that I am working in 2D space instead of 3D space because it might be easier to extract the value? Something like:

```
ss = Table[Plot[p1[z, t] /. soli, {z, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 10, .25}];
```

And then choose the last plot (i.e. so I'm pretty sure steady state is reached) with `ss[[40]]` but then I'm not sure how to get the output from `ss[[40]]`?

Part of me think I want to put it all into a `module`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you solve `p1[z, t] == 20` after `NDSolve` is done?  Or is there some reason you want to detect it during integration?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah I think that should work equally well for now. I want to eventually package in `Module` but I guess I could still do that by this approach too. Anyway, I was attempting to use `Solve` just now but it's not working out. Would you mind showing me the string of code to solve for `p1[z,t]==20`?

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WhenEvent[cond, act]` works in *time*, i.e., an event happens only when a time step causes the condition `cond` to change from `False` to `True`, save the special cases such as `f == c` described in the documentation.  Those subtleties aside, the main thing to understand in using `WhenEvent` in the method of lines is what is substituted for the dependent variables such as `p1[z, t]`.  If `z` is the spatial coordinate and `t = t0` is the current value of `t` (the time front), then an interpolating function of `z` representing `p1[z, t0]` is substituted.  You can deal with this as a function of `z` in any way you please.

Here is the OP's example modified appropriately:

```
soli = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bcs,
     WhenEvent[
      First@FindMinimum[{p1[z, t], 0 <= z <= 15}, {z, 10}] == 20, 
      Print[Join[
        FindRoot[(foo = p1[z, t]) == 20, {z, 0, 15}], {HoldPattern[t] -> t}]]]} /. params,
   {p1, p2}, {z, 0, 15}, {t, 0, 100}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 750}}];
(*  {z->11.8467, HoldPattern[t]->4.05457}  *)
```

Here is what is substituted for `p1[z, t]` in `WhenEvent`:

```
foo
(*  InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 15.}}, <>][z]  *)

Plot[foo, {z, 0, 15}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Either of these may be used in place of `First@FindMinimum[{p1[z, t], 0 <= z <= 15}, {z, 10}] == 20`:

```
NMinValue[{p1[z, t], 0 <= z <= 15}, z] == 20  (* quite slow *)
Min[p1[z, t] /. z -> "ValuesOnGrid"] == 20          (* fast but less accurate *)
```

Both of these return `{z->15., HoldPattern[t]->4.05457}`, the same time value but different `z` value as above.  Theoretically just taking the minimum of the interpolated values (`"ValuesOnGrid"`) should not always give the same answer as actually minimizing the function, but here it agrees with `NMinValue` and not with `FindMinimum`.  Global minimization (`NMinValue`, `NMinimize`) at each step by `NDSolve` can use up a lot of time.

*Addendum*

I suggested in a comment that determining when `p1[z, t] == 20` might be done after the solution has been computed, when appropriate.  It may be faster, too.
Here is a way to proceed if `soli` is a solution returned by `NDSolve` as above (with the extra braces).

First find the point in the computed values where `p1` first goes below 20. (*Edit note*: it is important that the expressions solved for in `NDSolve` are the functions `{p1, p2}`, not `{p1[z, t], p2[z, t]}` as in the OP's setup.  The code below used the OP's first result throughout.)

```
zt20 = Extract[
  p1["Grid"] /. First[soli],
  FirstPosition[p1["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First[soli], p_ /; p < 20]
  ]
p1 @@ % /. soli
(*
  {8.02, 4.46224}
  {19.9818}
*)
```

Then we can use this as the starting point to find the least `z` where `p1[z, t] == 20`.

```
{min, cp} = FindMinimum[
  {z, 0 <= z <= 15 && 0 <= t <= 100 && p1[z, t] == 20} /. First[soli],
  Evaluate@Transpose[{{z, t}, zt20}]]
p1[z, t] /. cp /. First[soli]
(*
  {8.00134, {z -> 8.00134, t -> 4.436}}
  20.
*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot-All you guys here are great! The `WhenEvent` approach answers my original question so I consider this answered. FYI though, your addendum isn't working out. Just running `zt20` I'm getting `Position specification Missing["NotFound"] in Extract[p1["Grid"], Missing["NotFound"]] is not applicable` and the output is `Extract[p1["Grid"], Missing["NotFound"]]`. Only thing I see is when I copy it over the `p` in `FirstPosition`'s `p<20` is green and not blue as in the post. Perhaps I'm missing your point about the extra braces.

Comment: @e3labs Oops, copied the wrong code.  See the update.  I usually prefer solving for the functions `{p1, p2}` instead of the value expressions `{p1[z, t], p2[z, t]}`, as it makes certain operations easier, such as computing residuals from `pde` and in this case, extracting properties of the `InterpolatingFunction`.  (The blue in the post is due to Stackexchange; I have green too, which indicates that `p` is a local variable used to name the pattern.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Michael