# Issues With WhenEvent in PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, event-detection

I am trying to solve the PDE below:

```
xInit = 1;
xMax = 10;
wid = 0.01;
T = 1000000;
Cc = 0.5

tMax = 1;
PDE = {D[c[x, t], t] == D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] + f[x, t], 
   D[f[x, t], t] == -f[x, t]/T, 
   f[x, 0] == (-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi, 
   c[x, 0] == 0, (D[c[x, t], x] /. {x -> 0}) == 0, 
   WhenEvent[c[x, t] - Cc == 0, f[x, t] -> 1]};
```

When I do so with:

```
PDESol = NDSolve[PDE, {c[x, t], f[x, t]}, {t, 0, tMax}, {x, 0, xMax}, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 0.001];
```

I get the following error:

```
NDSolve::nbnum1: The function value -0.5+InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},{5,7,0,{1001},{6},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{0.,0.01,0.02,<<45>>,0.48,0.49,<<951>>}},{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,<<952>>},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<951>>}},{Automatic}][x]==0 is not True or False when the arguments are <<1>>. >>
```

I understand that this has something to do with the method of lines and/or how Mathematica is solving this PDE, but I don't understand what is going wrong and how to fix my specific case.

Thanks!

Comment: What version are you using? I also get an NDSolve::bcart error (insufficient boundary conditions) as well.

Comment: Take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133528/problem-with-whenevent-in-solving-a-pde-with-ndsolvevalue

Comment: I'm using 10.0.2.0. The boundary condition error is not a problem; it's a common error in all similar problems I have tried and doesn't cause an issue with the solution so long as the boundary is placed sufficiently far. The difference between my question and the post above is that my replacement rule has two arguments in the function while the posited solution in that post has only 1... I don't see an obvious connection between the two.

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment, but also an answer to how to use `WhenEvent` in the `"MethodOfLines"`.  `WhenEvent` may not be the tool to use here.

`WhenEvent` is a [time event](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86509/4999). It occurs at a time $t=t_0$ for all $x$.  If you want an event to happen depending on the spatial location $x$ and time $t$, such as implied by the condition `c[x, t] - Cc == 0`, then you cannot do this with `WhenEvent`.

Here's how one might use `WhenEvent` in the OP's PDE.  I doubt it is the solution the OP wants, but the point of presenting it is to show how to use `WhenEvent` in a PDE.

As pointed out in the linked answer, the instances of `c[x, t]` in the `WhenEvent` code are replaced by an `InterpolatingFunction` with the following properties:

1. The [`"Grid"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/4999) of the `InterpolatingFunction` is the spatial grid being used in `NDSolve`.
2. The [`"ValuesOnGrid"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/4999) of the `InterpolatingFunction` are the values of `c[x, t0]` at `t0`, where `t0` equals the time of the event, and for `x` ranging over the spatial grid.

In an action such as `f[x, t] -> val`, the expression `val` needs to evaluate to a value for `f[x, t0]` for `x` ranging over the spatial grid.  Consequently in the case at hand, `val` needs to be vector of the same length as the spatial grid.

One further complication is that `WhenEvent`, while having the attribute `HoldAll`, evaluates some of its arguments in preparation for integrating the differential equation.  So it seemed to me that I had to create functions that would not evaluate until the `InterpolatingFunction` for `c[x, t]` was substituted.  One can see in the plots below that this works.  Again, it might not be what the OP wants; however, it might show the OP whether or not `WhenEvent` will address her or his needs.

```
maxval[if : InterpolatingFunction[___][x_]] := 
  Max[if /. x -> "ValuesOnGrid"];  (* could be Min[] or some other function *)
fnew[if : InterpolatingFunction[___][x_]] := 
  ConstantArray[1, Length[if /. x -> "Grid"]];
PDE = {D[c[x, t], t] == D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] + f[x, t], 
   D[f[x, t], t] == -f[x, t]/T, 
   f[x, 0] == (-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi, 
   c[x, 0] == 0, (D[c[x, t], x] /. {x -> 0}) == 0, 
   WhenEvent[maxval[c[x, t]] == Cc, f[x, t] -> fnew[c[x, t]]]};

sol = NDSolve[PDE, {c[x, t], f[x, t]}, {t, 0, tMax}, {x, 0, xMax}, 
  MaxStepFraction -> 0.001]
```

> NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions...

```
Plot3D[c[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

We can see the event happened around `t = 0.61`:

```
Plot3D[f[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

IIRC, `WhenEvent` in PDEs is not extensively documented.  The example in the docs for `WhenEvent` does not depend on the spatial variable(s).  For this reason, I thought this explanation would helpful for the site.  (Maybe it deserves its own question?)

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for the lucid and useful response. This information is indeed missing from the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF can be simplified by integrating the equation for $f (x,t)$ independently of $c (x,t)$, and then completing the definition of $f (x,t)$ on the line $c(x,t)=Cc$. The result is shown below.

```
xInit = 1;
xMax = 10;
wid = 0.01;
T = 1000000;
Cc = 0.5;

tMax = 1;

PDE = {D[c[x, t], t] == 
    D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
     If[c[x, t] == Cc, 1, 
      Exp[-t/T]*(-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi], c[x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][c][0, t] == 0, c[xMax, t] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[PDE, c, {t, 0, tMax}, {x, 0, xMax}, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 0.001];

f[x_, t_] := 
 If[sol[x, t] == Cc, 1, 
  Exp[-t/T]*(-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi]
{ContourPlot[sol[x, t], {x, 0, 4}, {t, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "c(t,x)", FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}], 
 ContourPlot[f[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "f(x,t)"], 
 Plot[f[x, 0], {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x,0)"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

In the statement of the author can not even see the line `c[x,t]-Cc==0`. I added code to solve this problem.

```
xInit = 1;
xMax = 10;
wid = 0.01;
T = 1000000;
Cc = 0.5;

tMax = 1;
PDE = {D[c[x, t], t] == D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] + f[x, t], 
   D[f[x, t], t] == -f[x, t]/T, 
   f[x, 0] == (-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi, c[x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][c][0, t] == 0, c[xMax, t] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[c[x, t] - Cc == 0, f[x, t] -> 1]};
sol = NDSolve[PDE, {c[x, t], f[x, t]}, {t, 0, tMax}, {x, 0, xMax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}] // Quiet
{ContourPlot[c[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 4}, {t, 0, tMax}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "c(t,x)", FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}], 
 ContourPlot[f[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, tMax}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "f(x,t)"], 
 Plot[{(-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi, f[x, t] /. sol /. t -> 0,
    f[x, t] /. sol /. t -> tMax}, {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f"}]}
```

[image: fig2]
Generally speaking the option`WhenEvent[c[x, t] - Cc == 0, f[x, t] -> 1]` does not give the desired effect, so I wrote another code in which on the line $c (x, t) = Cc$, the function is defined as $t = t0 (x)$.Then the solution is determined. So that we can clearly see the effect I put T = 10.

```
xInit = 1;
xMax = 10;
wid = 0.01;
T = 10;
Cc = 0.5;
tMax = 1;
PDE1 = {D[c[x, t], t] == 
    D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
     If[t >= t0[x], Exp[-(t - t0[x])/T], 
      Exp[-t/T]*(-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi], c[x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][c][0, t] == 0, c[xMax, t] == 0};
PDE = {D[c[x, t], t] == D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] + f[x, t], 
   D[f[x, t], t] == -f[x, t]/T, 
   f[x, 0] == (-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi, c[x, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][c][0, t] == 0, c[xMax, t] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolveValue[PDE, c, {t, 0, tMax}, {x, 0, xMax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 800, "MaxPoints" -> 1000, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];

t0 = Interpolation[
  Table[{x, t /. FindRoot[sol1[x, t] == Cc, {t, .5}]}, {x, 0, 2, .1}]]
Sol2 = NDSolveValue[PDE1, c, {t, 0, tMax}, {x, 0, xMax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 800, "MaxPoints" -> 1000, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];

f1[x_, t_] := 
 If[t >= t0[x], Exp[-(t - t0[x])/T], 
  Exp[-t/T]*(-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi]
{ContourPlot[Sol2[x, t], {x, 0, 4}, {t, 0, tMax}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "c(t,x)", FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}], 
 ContourPlot[f1[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, tMax}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "f(x,t)"], 
 Plot[{(-ArcTan[(x - xInit)/wid] + Pi/2)/Pi, f1[x, t] /. t -> 0, 
   f1[x, t] /. t -> tMax}, {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f"}]}
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86490/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-trounev-issues-with-whenevent-in-pdes).